# Setting .py file to notepad as default mistakenly

Tags: windows, file-association

I mistakenly set .py file to notepad as default mistakenly and it opens .py as txt file, but I don't want to open .py files with any program. I searched stackoverflow but solutions did not work for me. How can I solve it?

Answer (score 1):

Not a python-related question.

- Open Command Prompt in Administrator Mode.
- Type `assoc .py` at the prompt. (If the association is set with notepad, the same will be shown.)
- To **not associate `.py` with any program** (careful!) type `assoc .py=`. This sets the association to a non-existent value - simply, deletes it.

Comment: It says "File association not found for extension .py" even though .py is associated with notepad.

Comment: @blitz1 So when you double-click a `.py` file it opens directly in notepad?

Comment: You should first try "open with" -> "choose another app" on a .py script; select the "Python" app in the list that has a rocket on its icon and choose the option to always use it. If the "Python" app is missing, repair the "Python 3.x" and "Python Launcher" installations, and try the "open with" dialog again.

Comment: `assoc` only works on "HKLM\Software\Classes" for the system, so it requires administrator access. Even if you change the default value in "HKLM\Software\Classes\.py" at the system level to a progid such as "Python.File", it doesn't override a default in "HKCU\Software\Classes\.py" at the user level. Even without the latter, `assoc` doesn't override the shell API's current selection in "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.py" in the "OpenWithList" subkey, or a locked user choice in the "UserChoice" subkey.

Answer (score 0):

Probably, this one:
How do you remove a default program association for file types in Windows 7?

https://superuser.com/questions/49615/how-do-you-remove-a-default-program-association-for-file-types-in-windows-7

Comment: These suggestions dont work unfortunately, it seems that I need to format pc :(